# Print current vue-view with electron.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

How can I print the current web page view rendered by vue when using electron? The normal js-function `window.print()` prints empty. So what's the electron way? Is there a possibility to silent print without converting to .pdf?

Answer (score 0):

To print current Window use below code

```
let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
```

or

```
 let win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0];
```

to print

```
  win.webContents.print(options, (success, failureReason) => { 
            if (!success) console.log(failureReason); 
      
            console.log('Print Initiated'); 
        }); 
    });
```

full_code :

```
const electron = require('electron') 
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow; 
  
var current = document.getElementById('current');  
var options = { 
    silent: false, 
    printBackground: true, 
    color: false, 
    landscape: false, 
    pagesPerSheet: 1, 
    collate: false, 
    copies: 1, 
    header: 'Header of the Page', 
    footer: 'Footer of the Page'
} 
  
current.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
    let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(); 
    
  
    win.webContents.print(options, (success, failureReason) => { 
        if (!success) console.log(failureReason); 
  
        console.log('Print Initiated'); 
    }); 
});
```